# patching text files

Tags: python, diff, patch

I'm trying to successively build up a text file with diff patches.
starting from an empty text file I need to apply 600+ patches to end up with the final document (a text I have written + tracked the changes with mercurial). to each change in the file extra information needs to be added, so I can't simply use *diff* and *patch* in the commandline.

I have spent all day to write (and re-write) a tool that parses the diff files and makes changes to the text file accordingly, but one of the diff files makes my program behave in a way that I can't make any sense of.

this function gets called for each of the diff files:

```
# filename = name of the diff file
# date = extra information to be added as a prefix to each added line
def process_diff(filename, date):
    # that's the file all the patches will be applied to
    merge_file = open("thesis_merged.txt", "r")
    # map its content to a list to manipulate it in memory
    merge_file_lines = []
    for line in merge_file:
        line = line.rstrip()
        merge_file_lines.append(line)
    merge_file.close()

    # open for writing:
    merge_file = open("thesis_merged.txt", "w")

    # that's the diff file, containing all the changes
    diff_file = open(filename, "r")
    print "-", filename, "-" * 20

    # also map it to a list
    diff_file_lines = []
    for line in diff_file:
        line = line.rstrip()

        if not line.startswith("\\ No newline at end of file"): # useless information ... or not?
        diff_file_lines.append(line)

    # ignore header:
    #--- thesis_words_0.txt 2010-12-04 18:16:26.020000000 +0100
    #+++ thesis_words_1.txt 2010-12-04 18:16:26.197000000 +0100
    diff_file_lines = diff_file_lines[2:]

    hunks = []
    for i, line in enumerate(diff_file_lines):
        if line.startswith("@@"):
            hunks.append( get_hunk(diff_file_lines, i) )

    for hunk in hunks:
        head = hunk[0]
        # @@ -252,10 +251,9 @@
        tmp = head[3:-3].split(" ") # [-252,10] [+251,9]
        line_nr_minus = tmp[0].split(",")[0]
        line_nr_minus = int(line_nr_minus[1:]) # 252
        line_nr_plus = tmp[1].split(",")[0]
        line_nr_plus = int(line_nr_plus[1:]) # 251

        for j, line in enumerate(hunk[1:]):
            if line.startswith("-"):
            # delete line from the file in memory
            del merge_file_lines[line_nr_minus-1]

        plus_counter = 0 # counts the number of added lines
        for k, line in enumerate(hunk[1:]):
            if line.startswith("+"):
                # insert line, one after another
                merge_file_lines.insert((line_nr_plus-1)+plus_counter, line[1:])
                plus_counter += 1

    for line in merge_file_lines:
        # write the updated file back to the disk
        merge_file.write(line.rstrip() + "\n")

    merge_file.close()
    diff_file.close()
    print "\n\n"


    def get_hunk(lines, i):
        hunk = []
        hunk.append(lines[i])
        # @@ -252,10 +251,9 @@

        lines = lines[i+1:]

        for line in lines:
            if line.startswith("@@"):
                # next hunk begins, so stop here
                break
            else:
                hunk.append(line)

            return hunk
```

the diff files look like this -- here the trouble maker:

```
--- thesis_words_12.txt 2011-01-17 20:35:50.804000000 +0100
+++ thesis_words_13.txt 2011-01-17 20:35:51.057000000 +0100
@@ -245 +245,2 @@
-As
+Per
+definition
@@ -248,3 +249 @@
-already
-proposes,
-"generative"
+generative
@@ -252,10 +251,9 @@
-that
-something
-is
-created
-based
-on
-a
-set
-of
-rules.
+"having
+the
+ability
+to
+originate,
+produce,
+or
+procreate."
+<http://www.thefreedictionary.com/generative>
```

output:

```
[...]

Per
definition
the
"generative"
generative
means
"having
the
ability
to
originate,
produce,
or
procreate."
<http://www.thefreedictionary.com/generative>
that

[...]
```

all the previous patches reproduce the text just as expected. I have rewritten this many times, but that buggy behavior persists -- so right now I am clueless.

I'd be very thankful for hints and tips on how to do this differently. thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT:**
- in the end each line is supposed to look like this: `{date_and_time_of_text_change}word`

it's basicly about keeping track at what date and time a word was added to the text.

Comment: Can't you apply one patch using `diff`, make your necessary changes and do the same with the next patch file. What extra information has to be added?

Comment: If Elalfer's suggestion doesn't work for some reason, have a look at [python-patch](http://code.google.com/p/python-patch/).  Or even better, use the mercurial lib itself -- it is written in Python.

Comment: Why not use `patch(1)`? http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch

Comment: I also thought that it must be possible with diff / patch, but apparently it's not: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/how-to-force-a-malformed-patch-856865/

Comment: You've asked the wrong question. The correct question is, "why oh why am I using a single space for indentation?"

Comment: how exaclty would you use the mercurial lib, Elalfer? can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: You are using Python to make changes in diff files so that these then can be applied to some files in the end? Have you tried modifying these files directly instead? It's probably way easier.

Answer (score 1):

there was indeed a bug in the code -- I wasn't interpreting the diff files correctly (didn't realize there needed to be a line shift, when there are multiple hunks in one diff file)

```
def process_diff(filename, date, step_nr):
    merge_file = open("thesis_merged.txt", "r")
    merge_file_lines = [line.rstrip() for line in merge_file]
    merge_file.close()

    diff_file = open(filename, "r")
    print "-", filename, "-"*2, step_nr, "-"*2, date

    diff_file_lines = [line.rstrip() for line in diff_file]
    hunks = []
    for i, line in enumerate(diff_file_lines):
        if line.startswith("@@"):
            hunks.append( get_hunk(diff_file_lines, i) )
    diff_file.close()

    line_shift = 0
    for hunk in hunks:
        head = hunk[0]
        # @@ -252,10 +251,9 @@
        tmp = head[3:-3].split(" ") # [-252,10] [+251,9]

        line_nr_minus = tmp[0].split(",")[0]
        minusses = 1
        if len( tmp[0].split(",") ) > 1:
            minusses = int( tmp[0].split(",")[1] )
        line_nr_minus = int(line_nr_minus[1:]) # 252

        line_nr_plus = tmp[1].split(",")[0]
        plusses = 1
        if len( tmp[1].split(",") ) > 1:
            plusses = int( tmp[1].split(",")[1] )
        line_nr_plus = int(line_nr_plus[1:]) # 251

        line_nr_minus += line_shift

        #@@ -248,3 +249 @@
        #-already
        #-proposes,
        #-"generative"
        #+generative

        if hunk[1]: # -
            for line in hunk[1]:
                del merge_file_lines[line_nr_minus-1]

        plus_counter = 0
        if hunk[2]: # +
            for line in hunk[2]:
                prefix = ""
                if len(line) > 1:
                    prefix = "{" + date + "}"
                merge_file_lines.insert((line_nr_plus-1)+plus_counter, prefix + line[1:])
                plus_counter += 1

        line_shift += plusses - minusses
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use parser from [python-patch](http://code.google.com/p/python-patch/) - at least you'll be able to apply hunks one by one manually to see which one fails. API is not stable, but parser is, so you can just copy patch.py from trunk/ to your project. It would be nice to get some proposal on desired API, though.